# Aggregate several JaCoCo .exec files into a single Coverage report with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, integration-testing, jacoco-plugin

**Situation**
I'm working on a Spring Boot application that is coming along nicely, but the build-test cycle takes too long to be practical in a plain Dev environment.

So, I recently decided to split-up my unit-tests and integration tests. The integration tests are based on Cucumber whereas the unit tests are plain JUnit 5 tests.

For this I used the Gradle plugin `org.unbroken-dome.test-sets` which nicely creates the relevant sourceSets etc.

```
testSets {
    intTest { dirName = 'int-test' }
}
```

Everything is working nicely and my tests are executing as intended. The unit tests are still executed when I do a build and the integration tests are executed when I call `gradlew intTest'. This is by design, as I don't want to execute all tests all the time.

After running the tests, I also have a `jacoco/test.exec` file and a `jacoco/inttest.exec` file. All by design and as advertised by the test-sets plugin.

**Problem**
Here's my problem. When I had all my tests still in the test-SourceSet, so before the split and with only the `test.exec` file generated, JaCoCo reported a coverage of around 75%. But now that I have split up the tests and having the `test.exec` and `intTest.exec` files, JaCoCo only reports a coverage of 15%, which is about right considering the extent of my unit tests and integration tests.

**Question**
How can I get JaCoCo to use both the `test.exec` and the `intTest.exec` files to report the coverage and allow for the coverage verification task to consider both again?

**Relevant Code**
Here is some of the relevant code:
jacoco.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

// -----------------------------------------------------------
//
// JaCoCo
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:${jacocoToolVersion}:runtime"
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "${jacocoToolVersion}"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/Html")
        csv.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.csv")
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = minCodeCoverage
            }
        }
    }
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

Snippet from build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

and

```
testSets {
    intTest { dirName = 'int-test' }
}

intTest.mustRunAfter test
check.dependsOn intTest

test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out or pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, you know that once you've articulated your question, you know what to Google? Well after some more digging around I got some inspiratipon that gave me this as a jacocoTestReport definition:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/Html")
        csv.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.csv")
    }
}
```

The mistake I had made was in that I had the exec files aggregated in the jacocoTestCoverageVerification section, instead of the jacocoReport.

So, putting the executionData part in the right place, gave me the correct coverage values again. Yoohoo!!!