# How to get or parse coverage persentage of Jacoco report in GitHub Actions

Tags: build.gradle, github-actions, jacoco-plugin

I have Spring Boot app it uses gradle for build and package. I have configured Jacoco plugin and generating report in my local as HTML. I want to include it in my GitHub build workflow so whenever build runs I want to upload/store that Jacoco generated html report in the branch in which build is running. Is it possible using GitHub Actions?

Also once Jacoco build report is created want to extract final code coverage percentage of that build (this percentage is only for my defined coverage rule) and create a badge in the repository in which build is running.

**EDIT**

```
test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.6"
    //reportsDirectory = file("$buildDir/report/")
}


jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/Html")
        csv.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.csv")
    }
}

//Test coverage Rule to make sure code coverage is 100 %
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            element = 'CLASS'
            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                minimum = 1.0
            }
            excludes = [
                    'com.cicd.herokuautodeploy.model.*',
                    'com.cicd.herokuautodeploy.HerokuautodeployApplication',
                    'com.cicd.herokuautodeploy.it.*'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkFlow File**

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Gradle whenever Pull and Merge request to main branch
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-gradle

name: Build WorkFlow - Building and Validating Test Coverage

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main,dev ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11
      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Generate JaCoCo Badge
        id: jacoco
        uses: cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator@v2.0.1

      - name: Log coverage percentage
        run: |
                echo "coverage = ${{ steps.jacoco.outputs.coverage }}"
                echo "branch coverage = ${{ steps.jacoco.outputs.branches }}"

      - name: Commit the badge (if it changed)
        run: |
          if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
                  git config --global user.name 'UserName'
                  git config --global user.email 'useremail@gmail.com'
                  git add -A
                  git commit -m "Autogenerated JaCoCo coverage badge"
                  git push
          fi

      - name: Upload JaCoCo coverage report
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: jacoco-report
          path: reports/jacoco/
```

**Error**

File "/JacocoBadgeGenerator.py", line 88, in computeCoverage
with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv'

Comment: Yes, you need to create `target/site/jacoco/` and symlink it to the actual folder where gradle generates `jacoco.csv`

Comment: @VonC Thanks for direction and input. But I am not sure about symlink as im more of Java developer. Should I do it in my workflow file? Any guidance will really help

Comment: That or modify the gradle configuration in order to generate the csv file in the maven-like expected folder.

Comment: @VonC changing the report folder to maven like path is not working. Plugin is able to create csv file in given location but in GitAction badge generator not been able to recognize it's seems. I guess only option is symlink not sure how to do it. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: In the workflow, befire calling the plugin, I wouldcheckout, create the folder and symlink, similar to https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/actions/runs/350393237/workflow#L80-L86

Answer (score 4):

Disclosure: I am the author of the cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator GitHub Action that this question concerns.

Although the default behavior assumes Maven's location of the jacoco.csv, there is an action input that can be used to indicate the location of the jacoco report. So in your case, with gradle, you can change the cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator step of your workflow to the following (if you use gradle's default location and filename for the report):

```
  - name: Generate JaCoCo Badge
    uses: cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator@v2
    with:
      jacoco-csv-file: build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.csv
```

It looks like your gradle configuration changed the report location though, so you will need the following in order to coincide with your report location and filename:

```
  - name: Generate JaCoCo Badge
    id: jacoco
    uses: cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator@v2
    with:
      jacoco-csv-file: build/reports/jacoco/jacoco.csv
```

The `id: jacoco` is just because one of your later steps in your workflow is referring to the action outputs through that id.

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure jacoco to generate a `jacoco.csv` file, then the GitHub Action [`jacoco-badge-generator`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jacoco-badge-generator) can generate the requested badge.

[image: Jacoco badge]

See for instance "[Use Jacoco And GitHub Actions to Improve Code Coverage](https://graciano.dev/2020/08/25/use-jacoco-and-github-actions-to-improve-code-coverage/)" from [Rodrigo Graciano](https://twitter.com/rodrigograciano) for an example of [`pom.xml` project configuration](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/75b93337df25915794d613c216042c36df6f0be3/pom.xml) to generate the report during build.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For a [gradle example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65982616/6309):

```java
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/Html")
        csv.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.csv")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think given GitHub Action will work only for gradle. When I used above given config its failing as that action is looking for 'target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv' by default. Even though I changed in the workflow

Comment: @springbootlearner "given GitHub Action will work only for gradle.": considering your question is tagged "gradle", this is a good thing, no?

Comment: @springbootlearner But yes, https://github.com/cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator assumes maven, not gradle. Simply add a symlink from `'target/site/jacoco` to `${buildDir}/reports/jacoco` and that action will work.